# Newtype pattern in TypeScript with type guard and intersection types

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, newtype

I was reading this [article](https://kubyshkin.name/posts/newtype-in-typescript/) about the newtype pattern in TS.

The author shows the difference between using intersection types and a fake box type. The latter is the one you foun mainly in all implementations (see for instance fp-ts and the lib newtype-ts), because of the lack of invariants described as the end of the section 'Intersection types':

> More importantly, since TypeScript is structurally typed we can pass values of our newtype anywhere the base type is expected. This can be very nice in general, as we can use the type in all the utility functions we might have for original, but also could be quite undesired if we want to maintain certain invariants of the value:

```
type SortedArray<T> =
    T[] & { readonly __tag: unique symbol };

function sort<T>(array: T[]): SortedArray<T> {
    return [...array].sort() as SortedArray<T>;
}

const sorted = sort([3, 7, 1]);

// no error here, but should be:
const notSortedAnymore = sorted.concat(2);
```

I've implemented the example myself in TS 4.4 and I may be missing something since the type of `notSortedAnymore` is clearly not a `SortedArray` but a `number[]`.

To me, it does not seem like a problem, since the type system is not misled by the use of the `concat` method. I have a SortedArray, I concatenate the number 2, it is not possible to infer that it is still a SortedArray, so it gives my a array of numbers.

Given the fact that in TS, the use of intersection types for such a pattern allows to have a easier (maybe even clearer) implementation (= you can avoid the use of the `lift` function to apply simple functions like `concat`), **why the newtype pattern is generally implemented using a fake box type instead of the intersection types?** and **what am I missing here?**

Thanks a lot

Best

Comment: It seems as the author expects from a newype that it can use all the methods of the orignal type without implicit type casts just like Haskell does with newtypes and type classes. I agree that implicit type casts are bad just because they are implicit. I don't follow with the lifting, though. Using `from`/`to` explicitly doesn't _accidentally convert_ anything but converts it intentionally.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it is because TS is doing an implicit casting by using an intersection type that it is better to use a fake box type to avoid that behaviour? (I guess the lift method is here to avoid converting from one type to another by mistake (you have Euros, you convert to number, you apply your function, you forget to convert it back. By using lift, you prevent that mistake since it is not needed any longer)

Comment: Seems to be I have missed the point. I m removing my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I may be missing something since the type of `notSortedAnymore` is clearly not a `SortedArray` but a `number[]`.

It's not just a TS 4.4 thing, I've also tried older versions of TypeScript and the result is no different.

I believe the method in the example was just badly (or mistakenly?) chosen. Instead, it should have been

```
type SortedArray<T> = T[] & { readonly __tag: unique symbol };

function sort<T>(array: T[]): SortedArray<T> {
    return [...array].sort() as SortedArray<T>;
}

const sorted = sort([3, 7, 1]);

// no error here, but should be:
sorted.push(2);
```

Now `sorted` is still a `SortedArray<number>` but its elements are not sorted. The problem with structural typing is that it allows all methods defined on the original type to be called, no matter if they are valid for the newtype or not. `slice` would be fine, `push`, `pop` or `reverse` are not.

And it's not limited to methods, one could also define functions like

```
function shuffle<T extends number[]>(arr: T): T {
    arr[0] = 4; // chosen by fair dice roll :-)
    return arr;
}
```

and use it like

```
const sorted = sort([3, 7, 1]);
const shuffled = shuffle(sorted);
```

where `shuffled` will be inferred to be a `SortedArray<number>`.

Comment: Ok! I get it and so the fake box type will prevent that behavior! Thanks for your answer, was very helpful!

Comment: @Corentin Took me a bit until the switch flipped :-)